# Auto-renewal Subscription Refund Policy

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have certain queries regarding iOS in-app purchase refund policy:

1. What Happens if a user who have purchased an auto-renewal subscription from an app and asks Apple for refund?
2. If Apple refunds the user, does the auto-renewal subscription remain active till the duration he have previously purchased it for? or it cancels out immediately.
3. How does the application people know that some guy has asked for refund from their subscriptions?

Please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policies

Comment: No, it is not off-topic, no more so than any other question about iOS programming, because the questions relate directly to tasks dealing with the StoreKit APIs. The accepted answer is actually a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to see WWDC 2012 video 308 "Managing subscriptions with In-App purchase". They talk about it starting at 13:30.
Anyway,

1. If you talk about customer's money - I don't know. And I would like to know too.
2. After refunding, if you send receipt to Apple server for verifying, you'll get `21006` status, even if `expire_date` is still in future. If the subscription was refunded, you'll get additional `cancellation_date` entry in received JSON, which stands for time and date, when subscription was refunded (cancelled).
3. You don't receive any special signal about refunding. But you can periodically verify receipt and check received JSON object: if there is value for `cancellation_date` key, then subscription is cancelled.

Comment: customer gets his 100% money after refund.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran and who is paying that money? Apple or developer?

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi Apple